# Wrapping long text in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to wrap long text elements to a width.  The example here is taken from [Bostock's `wrap` function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321), but seems to have 2 problems: firstly the result of wrap has not inherited the element's x value (texts are shifted left); secondly it's wrapping on the same line, and `lineHeight` argument has no effect.

Grateful for suggestions.  http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/bk87ja3g/

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .style("background-color", '#ddd');

dat = ["Ukip has peaked, but no one wants to admit it - Nigel Farage now resembles every other politician", 
       "Ashley Judd isn't alone: most women who talk about sport on Twitter face abuse",
       "I'm on list to be a Mars One astronaut - but I won't see the red planet"];

svg.selectAll("text").data(dat).enter().append("text")
    .attr('x', 25)
    .attr('y', function(d, i){ return 30 + i * 90; })
    .text(function(d){ return d; })
    .call(wrap, 250);

function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 1,
        lineHeight = 1.2, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bostock's original function assumes that the `text` element has an initial `dy` set.  It also drops any `x` attribute on the `text`.  Finally, you changed the `wrap` function to start at `lineNumber = 1`, that needs to be `0`.

Refactoring a bit:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0, //<-- 0!
        lineHeight = 1.2, // ems
        x = text.attr("x"), //<-- include the x!
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = text.attr("dy") ? text.attr("dy") : 0; //<-- null check
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk87ja3g/1/).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))
```

In the example you've linked to, `dy` is set on the `text` elements, but not in your case. So you're getting `NaN` there which in turn causes the `dy` for the `tspan` to be `NaN`. Fix by assigning 0 to `dy` if `NaN`:

```
dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")) || 0
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bk87ja3g/2/).